# Eclipse EAR module publish log

Tags: eclipse

I am using weblogic worshop to develop my spring based application. Basically it takes lot of time to publish the application to weblogic server. Is there any way to find out what’s going on when eclipse try to build and deploy the project? Basically does it maintain any log file?

Thanks ,
Manoj

Answer (score 1):

Weblogic does a stupid thing according to my experience. If you deploy some WAR, it extracts the libraries in it, and does some analysis in them. You can avoid this behaviour by removing the "static" (not changed by you during work) libraries from the war during development. After removal, add them to system classpath of the domain. It will publish and start a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

You will find better support for developing Spring applications for WebLogic Server if you migrate to Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse. Workshop is legacy software that is no longer being actively developed. Using Workshop is only necessary for those developing with the deprecated Apache Beehive framework.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/index.html

OEPE includes a much newer publisher implementation, so you may find your issue resolved. If not, please post to OEPE forum for direct access to people who can answer you question.

Cannot post a forum link, but you can find it from the above URL or via Google.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Konstantin and Gabor for replying to my question.

Konstantin - I am using Oracle Weblogic workshop 10.3 and I am restricted to use this IDE only.I guess it has OEPE correct me if I am wrong.Also I tried the FastSwap action but everytime I save the changes to a java file the server says -'Publish' and I have to republish the entire application which is taking lot of time.

Thanks,
Manoj